# Silverlight create control template for TabControl

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol, controltemplate

I use `Silverlight 5` and want to use control template for `TabControl`. how can do it.
In `WPF` you can use below code for control template of `TabControl`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TabPanel Grid.Column="1" Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the easiest way to customise the TabControl template is with Expression Blend.

However, the ControlTemplate for a Silverlight TabControl should look mostly the same as your example. There are a couple of notable differences though.

`TargetType` syntax is different

```
TargetType="TabControl"
```

There is also no `ContentSource` property on the `ContentPresenter`